# Jenkins lock/exclusion based on job parameters?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I have some Jenkins jobs (say job-A and job-B), but need to prevent any of them running simultaneously if a particular parameter is the same. So if job-A is started with parameter foo=42, and an attempt is made to run job-B with parameter foo=42, that attempt must be prevented. But running job-B with parameter foo=17 (while job-A|foo=42) is running is fine (as is running job-A|foo=17).

I can figure out a way to do this using shell scripts and lock files, but wondering if it is possible within Jenkins itself or using a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get this done with the [Lockable Resource Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/lockable-resources/), which allows you to acquire locks on resources and wait until they are released to perform certain pipeline operations.

First, create a lock called `foo42lock`, and the following are two sample pipelines. Since you don't want to wait until the lock is released you can set `skipIfLocked: true` flag when acquiring the lock, so the pipeline will continue if the lock is not acquirable.

**JobA**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters { string(name: 'foo', defaultValue: '', description: '') }
    stages {
        stage("StageA") {
            steps {
                script {
                    if(foo == "42") {
                        lock(resource: 'foo42lock', skipIfLocked: true) {
                            echo "Foo is 42 Lock aquired and Job A Running"
                            runSteps()
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "No lock needed"
                        runSteps()
                    }
                        
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

def runSteps(){
    echo "Storing the steps externally to reuse. Running Job A"
    sleep 30
}
```

**JobB**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters { string(name: 'foo', defaultValue: '', description: '') }
    stages {
        stage("StageB") {
            steps {
                script {
                    if(foo == "42") {
                        lock(resource: 'foo42lock', skipIfLocked: true) {
                            echo "Foo is 42 Lock aquired and Job B Running"
                            runSteps()
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "No lock needed"
                        runSteps()
                    }
                        
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

def runSteps(){
    echo "Storing the steps externally to reuse. Running Job B steps"
    sleep 30
}
```

Another way to achieve this would be, whenever either JobA or JobB is triggered if foo==42 then JobA can check if there is a build happening for JobB and whether the parameter is set to foo=42 and if a build is happening it can stop the build, and vice versa. Implementing this is also not that complex and can use Groovy scripts to implement the logic.

Comment: creating a lock for each possible combination of job and parameter is not an option (I have thousands of possible parameters). I know I can implement some scripts to achieve this, but was wondering if there's an in-built way